# Embed Instagram Post Programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, instagram, instagram-api

I couldn't able to embed instagram post programmatically.

I am using jquery and off course, Instagram's embed.js. Normally when you embed a post via instagram itslef it is giving something like this:

```
<blockquote class="instagram-media" data-instgrm-captioned data-instgrm-version="7" style=" background:#FFF; border:0; border-radius:3px; box-shadow:0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5),0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15); margin: 1px; max-width:658px; padding:0; width:99.375%; width:-webkit-calc(100% - 2px); width:calc(100% - 2px);"><div style="padding:8px;"> <div style=" background:#F8F8F8; line-height:0; margin-top:40px; padding:50.0% 0; text-align:center; width:100%;"> <div style=" background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACwAAAAsCAMAAAApWqozAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAFzUkdCAK7OHOkAAAAMUExURczMzPf399fX1+bm5mzY9AMAAADiSURBVDjLvZXbEsMgCES5/P8/t9FuRVCRmU73JWlzosgSIIZURCjo/ad+EQJJB4Hv8BFt+IDpQoCx1wjOSBFhh2XssxEIYn3ulI/6MNReE07UIWJEv8UEOWDS88LY97kqyTliJKKtuYBbruAyVh5wOHiXmpi5we58Ek028czwyuQdLKPG1Bkb4NnM+VeAnfHqn1k4+GPT6uGQcvu2h2OVuIf/gWUFyy8OWEpdyZSa3aVCqpVoVvzZZ2VTnn2wU8qzVjDDetO90GSy9mVLqtgYSy231MxrY6I2gGqjrTY0L8fxCxfCBbhWrsYYAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC); display:block; height:44px; margin:0 auto -44px; position:relative; top:-22px; width:44px;"></div></div> <p style=" margin:8px 0 0 0; padding:0 4px;"> <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BGuzuQ3tLk4/" style=" color:#000; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-style:normal; font-weight:normal; line-height:17px; text-decoration:none; word-wrap:break-word;" target="_blank">Bu işin Kitabını Yazmak Bizim İşimiz #aspnetmvc #webtasarım #Googlepartner</a></p> <p style=" color:#c9c8cd; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px; margin-bottom:0; margin-top:8px; overflow:hidden; padding:8px 0 7px; text-align:center; text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space:nowrap;">@karayel_tasarim tarafından paylaşılan bir fotoğraf (<time style=" font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px;" datetime="2015-07-16T08:19:37+00:00">16 Tem 2015, 01:19 PDT</time>)</p></div></blockquote>
```

When i request it with oEmbed response it quite similar:

```
{"provider_url": "https://www.instagram.com", "media_id": "490179663453772794_969629", "author_name": "alberto.t", "height": null, "thumbnail_url": "https://scontent-fra3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/e15/11280253_1438753469762560_1082518244_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=NDkwMTc5NjYzNDUzNzcyNzk0.2", "thumbnail_width": 612, "thumbnail_height": 612, "provider_name": "Instagram", "title": "Points of view. #hancock", "html": "\u003cblockquote class=\"instagram-media\" data-instgrm-captioned data-instgrm-version=\"7\" style=\" background:#FFF; border:0; border-radius:3px; box-shadow:0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5),0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15); margin: 1px; max-width:658px; padding:0; width:99.375%; width:-webkit-calc(100% - 2px); width:calc(100% - 2px);\"\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"padding:8px;\"\u003e \u003cdiv style=\" background:#F8F8F8; line-height:0; margin-top:40px; padding:50% 0; text-align:center; width:100%;\"\u003e \u003cdiv style=\" background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACwAAAAsCAMAAAApWqozAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAFzUkdCAK7OHOkAAAAMUExURczMzPf399fX1+bm5mzY9AMAAADiSURBVDjLvZXbEsMgCES5/P8/t9FuRVCRmU73JWlzosgSIIZURCjo/ad+EQJJB4Hv8BFt+IDpQoCx1wjOSBFhh2XssxEIYn3ulI/6MNReE07UIWJEv8UEOWDS88LY97kqyTliJKKtuYBbruAyVh5wOHiXmpi5we58Ek028czwyuQdLKPG1Bkb4NnM+VeAnfHqn1k4+GPT6uGQcvu2h2OVuIf/gWUFyy8OWEpdyZSa3aVCqpVoVvzZZ2VTnn2wU8qzVjDDetO90GSy9mVLqtgYSy231MxrY6I2gGqjrTY0L8fxCxfCBbhWrsYYAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC); display:block; height:44px; margin:0 auto -44px; position:relative; top:-22px; width:44px;\"\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e \u003cp style=\" margin:8px 0 0 0; padding:0 4px;\"\u003e \u003ca href=\"https://www.instagram.com/p/bNd86MSFv6/\" style=\" color:#000; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-style:normal; font-weight:normal; line-height:17px; text-decoration:none; word-wrap:break-word;\" target=\"_blank\"\u003ePoints of view. #hancock\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/p\u003e \u003cp style=\" color:#c9c8cd; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px; margin-bottom:0; margin-top:8px; overflow:hidden; padding:8px 0 7px; text-align:center; text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space:nowrap;\"\u003eAlberto Tretti (@alberto.t) taraf\u0131ndan payla\u015f\u0131lan bir foto\u011fraf (\u003ctime style=\" font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px;\" datetime=\"2013-07-01T04:46:31+00:00\"\u003e30 Haz 2013, 21:46 PDT\u003c/time\u003e)\u003c/p\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/blockquote\u003e\n\u003cscript async defer src=\"//platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js\"\u003e\u003c/script\u003e", "width": 658, "version": "1.0", "author_url": "https://www.instagram.com/alberto.t", "author_id": 969629, "type": "rich"}
```

I do not know what to do next?

I am using ASP.Net MVC but i have to solve this at front-end. Preferably with jQuery or JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

To get this to work you have to manually initialize the embed code on the page. You can do this by calling the globally available instgrm.Embeds.process() javascript method. See [Instagram Developer Documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/embedding/).